# Accept credit card payments for billing services iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, paypal, credit-card

I have an important question to ask here. First of all I don't know where to exactly post this question. Sorry about that.

It's about making an iPhone app. I've client from Constanta, Romania. He provides billing services to customers. The scenario is like this:

His customers submit their utility bills and the respective bill payments to him and from there on he takes care of submitting them on their behalf. And he takes service charges from the customers.

He wants to make an iOS app for this. Where in people will scan their bills via app and submit the bills along with the payment of the bill to him using their credit card (like stripe for iOS or PayPal) and then he submits their bills.

The question I have in mind is, does Apple allow this? to have such an app?

I have a doubt that this cannot be done at an individual level as he is not selling a tangible product in return for the money but a promise. Is my doubt correct?

But if the entity thats providing such services is properly legalized and has all the end user agreements and proper licenses available in the app for the user to accept, is it fine then to go ahead and make the app?

I want to know the possibilities of this scenario as this is a limited scope application and the target audience belongs to a particular area or community.

Would an adhoc distribution of the app work?

It would be great if someone can give me a good analysis of this requirement and the possibilities. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I would like to suggest to build app using third party payment gateways

eg.

```
1) ekashu credit call.
2) Dibs.
3) Payment Express.
4) SIX Payment gateway.
```

you can see above payment gateways in app which is developed by me.

1) https://itunes.apple.com/se/app/waytopark/id803005911?l=en&mt=8

2) https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/waytopark/id886660669?ls=1&mt=8

first two payment gateways implemented & rest two is in development/testing phase.

If you want to build and install application for limited area/community then you need to send application manually to that users for install OR install app manually from your end, OR build separate web application for download .ipa to install.

if you use AdHoc distribution for distribute app to that area/community, you could, but AdHoc distribution valid for one year and 100 devices only. App will work only up to valid provisional profiles (1 year).

first screen of app will have a enter code, code will be validate at server side, if valid code entered, app will open to use else block/stop processing. unique code will generate at your side and distribute code to each user which belongs to area or community. App upload on app store,instead of distribute manually because if you update app, you need to notify each user to install app updates that manage by app store and you don't need to distribute app manually using AdHoc distribution.

Hope this will help.

Comment: but this doesn't answer my question completely and that was about legalization. A person is charging money in return of a promise to submit the bills. Can Apple raise issues on this kind of app?

Comment: Apple will not raise any issues, you can take example of parking applications, follows same scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that Apple should probably not allow is if the App does sell virtual goods and you do not use In-App-Purchases.

Everything (legal) else is fine if you use some other services.